# Creating ChartLabels in scientific format over a range

Tags: formatting, labeling

I would like to shorten this repetitious code. Personally, I would save the labels in a separate variable and then just refer to the variable, like for example "ChartLabels -> mylabels". This way the plot function itself doesn't look cluttered.

```
ChartLabels -> {Rotate[
   "2\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(4\)]\)", 45 Degree],
  Rotate[Style["4\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(4\)]\)", 12], 
   45 Degree],
  Rotate[Style["6\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(4\)]\)", 12], 
   45 Degree],
  Rotate[Style["8\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(4\)]\)", 12], 
   45 Degree],
  Rotate[Style["1\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(5\)]\)", 12], 
   45 Degree],
  Rotate[Style["1.2\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(5\)]\)", 
    12], 45 Degree],
  Rotate[Style["1.4\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(5\)]\)", 
    12], 45 Degree],
  Rotate[Style["1.6\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(5\)]\)", 
    12], 45 Degree],
  Rotate[Style["1.8\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(5\)]\)", 
    12], 45 Degree],
  Rotate[Style["2\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(5\)]\)", 12], 
   45 Degree]}
```

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE! Your question needs more from your side. Here it's considered helpful and polite to show your own efforts and share your data and code attempts in a well [formatted form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question accordingly. Also, please take the [tour], it will help you understand the site. If  you write an [excellent question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) it will inspire great answers.

Comment: You could make things more compact with [`Iconize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Iconize.html). Is that what you are after? What have you tried?

Comment: Personally, I would save the labels in a separate variable and then just refer to the variable, like for example "ChartLabels -> mylabels". This way the plot function itself doesn't look cluttered.

Answer (score 3):

Another fast way would be the following

```
ChartLabels -> (Rotate[Style[ScientificForm[1. #  10^4], 12], 
 45 Degree] & /@ Range[2, 20,2])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way could be:

```
Clear[f];
f[num_Integer] := 
 RowBox[{NumberForm[10 First@#, {3, 1}], "x", 
      SuperscriptBox[10, Last@# - 1]}] &@ 
   MantissaExponent[1.0 num, 10] // DisplayForm
ChartLabels -> (Rotate[#, 45 Degree] & /@ 
   f /@ Range[2 10^4, 2 10^5, 2 10^4])
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

The advantage of using additional pieces of information provided by `MantissaExponent` is that another function `f2` can be defined and used (with minor style changes). For example:

```
f2[num_Integer] := 
 RowBox[{Framed[#, Background -> Yellow] &@
       NumberForm[10 First@#, {3, 1}], "x", 
      SuperscriptBox[10, Style[Last@# - 1, Red]]}] &@ 
   MantissaExponent[1.0 num, 10] // DisplayForm

ChartLabels -> (Rotate[#, 45 Degree] & /@ 
   f2 /@ Range[2 10^4, 2 10^5, 2 10^4])
```

[image]